# Can we add user defined function in operator chaining on a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have defined a function:

```
   def keep_alphabets(name):
       energy[name] = energy[name].map(lambda x : ' '.join([re.sub('[^A-Za-z]','',w) for w in x.split()]))
```

I have an existing data frame where I am using operator chaining.

```
   energy = (pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=17, skip_footer=0,na_values='...')
      .drop(['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1'], axis=1)
      .rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 2' : 'Country','Petajoules' : 'Energy Supply','Gigajoules' : 'Energy Supply per Capita',
                          '%' : '% Renewable'})
      .replace({'Country':{"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
                           "United States of America": "United States",
                           "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
                           "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region3": "Hong Kong"}})
      .head(227))
```

Can I add keep_alphabets function also here?

Comment: you can use `df.apply(func_name)`...

Comment: Use `df.apply` and pass the `lambda`.

Comment: What would the `name` argument be?

Comment: arguement will be a columns from the database in the form of pandas series. @IanS

Comment: Is it a single column that you want to modify in this way, or all columns?

Comment: Single column only for now.

Comment: So, did any of this work?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC last step should be `apply` if need use lambda function for each column of `df`:

```
.apply(lambda x : ' '.join([re.sub('[^A-Za-z]','',w) for w in x.split()]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following ..

```
# for single elements
def keep_alphabets_elem(s):
    return ' '.join([re.sub('[^A-Za-z]','',w) for w in s.split()]))

energy = (pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=17, skip_footer=0,na_values='...')
  .drop(['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1'], axis=1)
  .rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 2' : 'Country','Petajoules' : 'Energy Supply','Gigajoules' : 'Energy Supply per Capita',
                      '%' : '% Renewable'})
  .replace({'Country':{"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
                       "United States of America": "United States",
                       "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
                       "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region3": "Hong Kong"}})
  .apply(lambda x: keep_alphabets_elem(x['COL_NAME'], axis=1) # NEW
  .head(227))
```

Note that you need to use axis=1 to do this on rows instead of columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to modify a single column called `'col'`:

```
.assign(col=energy['col'].map(func))
```

where `func` is the lambda function you defined:

```
def func(x):
    return ' '.join([re.sub('[^A-Za-z]','',w) for w in x.split()])
```

If you want to put the column name in a variable `name='col'`:

```
.assign(**{name: energy[name].map(func)})
```